# html5 why is a click event causing a mouseout event?

Tags: javascript, css, html

From all the documentation I've read, a mouseout event is only called an element when the user actually moves the mouse outside the bounds of that element.

I have observed that a mouseout event is also fired on an element when the element is clicked and obscured such that the coordinates of the click overlap between the obscured element and the obscuring element.

Consider this element:
[image: obscured element]

When I click on the green section of the element (an area which overlaps with an obscuring element), I see inconsistent behavior across browsers. Chrome and Firefox do fire the mouseout event on the obscured element, whereas IE and Opera do not fire the mouseout event on the obscured element. Is there a "correct" behavior for this condition according to HTML/CSS specifications? The [CSS visual formating model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) doesn't say anything about event handling.

Here is the code:

```
$( '#button' ).on( 'click', function(e) {
    $( '#overlay' ).show();
    log( document.activeElement + ' has the focus' );
});

$( '#button' ).on( 'mouseout', function(e) {
    log( 'target: ' + e.relatedTarget.id );
    log( 'why are you mousing out?' );
});
```

and here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jmjpro/7Jp2G/6/.

Answer (score 2):

When you show the overlay, the mouse is no longer on top of the button.  By showing the overlay YOU are triggering the mouseout event.

Comment: it seems that you have restated what I already stated in my question. What you're saying is try for Chrome and Firefox, but not for IE and Opera. Is there a correct behavior according to any HTML/CSS specification?

Comment: I meant "true" not "try"

Answer (score 2):

Your overlay div is laid on top of the button div.

That is the reason when you click on button div, overlay div is shown and the mouseout event is triggered.

You can just test it by removing all css. It works exactly as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely positioned elements are not part of the page flow, they follow different rules. Because of this, the overlay doesn't count as part of the original div, which means the mouse is technically not over it anymore.